# Join to get a description

Tags: sql-server

Description table.

```
SELECT SelectionId,
           ProfileCategoryId,
           [Description]
FROM ProfileCategoryAllSelections
WHERE ProfileCategoryId = 34
```

[image]

My join.

```
SELECT a.SelectionId
       ,1 as 'SelectedSwitch'
FROM dbo.UsersMultiSelection a
JOIN dbo.[User] b ON a.UserId = b.UserId  
WHERE ( b.UserId = 1 AND b.ActiveSwitch = 1 AND 34 = a.ProfileCategoryId )
```

[image]

Now I want to get the description from the ProfileCategoryAllSelections table for the entry on the UsersMultiSelection table. But getting back to many rows. 6 for every row on my UsersMultiSelection table. I tried different joins with no luck.

```
SELECT a.SelectionId
           ,c.[Description]
           ,1 as 'SelectedSwitch'
FROM dbo.UsersMultiSelection a
JOIN dbo.[User] b ON a.UserId = b.UserId  
JOIN dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections c ON a.ProfileCategoryId = c.ProfileCategoryId  
WHERE ( b.UserId = 1 AND b.ActiveSwitch = 1 AND 34 = a.ProfileCategoryId )
```

[image]

Comment: Try this:

SELECT a.SelectionId, c.[Description], b.ActiveSwitch as 'SelectedSwitch'
FROM dbo.UsersMultiSelection a
JOIN dbo.[User] b ON a.UserId = b.UserId  
JOIN dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections c ON a.ProfileCategoryId = c.ProfileCategoryId  
WHERE ( b.UserId = 1 AND b.ActiveSwitch = 1 AND 34 = a.ProfileCategoryId )

Comment: Same results - 210 rows 6 per base table.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the contents of your **ProfileCategoryAllSelections** table? My speculation is you want to join to from **UsersMultiSelection** to **ProfileCategoryAllSelections** on **SelectionId** rather than **ProfileCategoryId**. Or maybe both.

Comment: Isaac - nailed it. Just needed to join on SelectionId. How do I get you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Isaac: Just needed to join on SelectionId.